# I wrote url validation regex but the regex is very slow

Tags: regex

I know this is slow because of `([\.\-][a-z0-9])*`. But I don't know how to optimize it.

```
^https:\/\/([a-z0-9]+([\.\-][a-z0-9])*)+(\.([a-z]{2,11}|[0-9]{1,5}))(:[0-9]{1,5})?(\/.*)?$
```

Comment: I think you don't need this construct `*)+` Omit the capture groups if you don't need them, and repeat the character class 1+ times and a single outer non capture group 0+ times. `^https:\/\/[a-z0-9]+(?:[.-][a-z0-9]+)*\.(?:[a-z]{2,11}|[0-9]{1,5})(?::[0-9]{1,5})?(\/.*)?$` https://regex101.com/r/TSxWjX/1

Comment: What should this regex accomplish and why do you think writing a new regex from scratch is going to work better than picking one of the many popular existing regexes for URL validation? For example, https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2396#appendix-B

Comment: Another great resource for URL validation patterns: https://mathiasbynens.be/demo/url-regex

Comment: @tripleee I need to accept only https protocol

Comment: `(?:[.-][a-z0-9]+)*` looks wrong, why would you want to accept a dot there?

Comment: @tripleee I want to validate url with subdomain also. and accept hyphen [-] only in between the url i.e https://example-hyphen.com (valid) , https://-example-hyphen.com (invalid)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to use this part `)*)+` in your pattern. This could also potentially lead to [catastrophic backtracking](https://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html).

**Note** that you only have to escape the backslash if the delimiters for the regex are also `/` and you don't have to escape the `[\.\-]`

If you don't need that capture groups afterwards, you can omit them.

```
^https:\/\/[a-z0-9]+(?:[.-][a-z0-9]+)*\.(?:[a-z]{2,11}|[0-9]{1,5})(?::[0-9]{1,5})?(\/.*)?$
```

The pattern matches:

- `^` Start of string
- `https:\/\/` Match `https://` As you only want to match https
- `[a-z0-9]+` Match 1+ times any of the listed
- `(?:[.-][a-z0-9]+)*` Optionally repeat matching `.` or `-` and 1+ times any of the listed
- `\.(?:[a-z]{2,11}|[0-9]{1,5})` Match either 2-11 times a char a-z or match 1-5 digits
- `(?::[0-9]{1,5})?` Optionally match `:` and 1-5 digits
- `(\/.*)? Optionally match` /` and the rest of the line
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/TSxWjX/1)